# proving the square of a number is the square of it's individual components

Tags: proof-verification

Given the number a:

$\ a^2\ = H$, where H is a perfect square.  Let :

$\ a= c*d\ $, where c are it's prime factors.

How do we prove that:

$\ a^2\ $ = $\ (c * d)^2\ $ = $\ c^2 * d^2\ $

Comment: if $a,c,d$ are naturals which i assume they are in this case, you essentially want to prove $c \cdot d = d \cdot c $ which is almost axiomatic

Comment: @mdave16, I want to prove (14)'s square is equal to the individual square of 7 and 2

Comment: stity's answer should be enough, unless you're looking to prove that multiplication is associative and commutative on the naturals, that is a slightly longer affair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The multiplication on the naturals is associative and commutative :

- Associative :
  $$a*(b*c)=(a*b)*c$$
- Commutative :
  $$a*b=b*a$$

So you get $$(c*d)*(c*d)=c*d*c*d=c*c*d*d=c^2*d^2$$